# How to resolve Two Subquery syntax error (syntax error at end of input)

Tags: post

I am trying to get for each row in my table - for the column "totaltime"
the below formula
"totaltime" - "average total time by user id" + "average total time all users"
I tried below query

```
SELECT  pt."totaltime" - subquery.mean_total_time + foo.global_mean_total_time 
            FROM "ABC" pt
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT "uid", AVG("totaltime") AS mean_total_time
                FROM "ABC"
                GROUP BY "uid"
            ) subquery ON pt."uid" = subquery."uid"
             JOIN (
                SELECT AVG("totaltime") AS global_mean_total_time
                FROM "ABC"
            ) foo
```

I am getting syntax error
ERROR: syntax error at end of input. The subquery looks correct. But the error is at line "foo" and not clear. How to solve it?

My table "ABC"

```
id   uid   time
1    "abc"   1
2    "abc"   2
3    "pqr"   3
4    "pqr"   4
```

I want

```
id   time
1    1 - (1.5) + 2.5 = 
.
.
.
```

where 1 is time of row, 1.5 is average time of user "abc"
and 2.5 is table average of time. how to do it